# CKEditor not displayed in JS file

Tags: ckeditor

I want to display textarea as CKEditor but it's not working in here, although it works in my html code.

I have a file global.js which I have included in my html code too as a script.

This is my function in global.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a#reply").one("click" , function() {
    var comCode = $(this).attr("name");
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.append("<br /><form action='index.php' method='post'><input 
       type='text' name='uname2' id='uname2' placeholder='Enter username' 
       required /><textarea class='ckeditor' name='editor' 
       placeholder='Enter your query' id='new-reply' required></textarea>
       <input type='hidden' name='code' value='"+comCode+"' /><input 
       type='submit' class='form-submit' id='form-reply' name='new_reply' 
       value='Reply' /></form>")
       //$(".chreply").toggle();
    });
 })
```

I even tried including:

```
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load( this.path + 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js' );
CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor' );
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a problem with my code or else is it that ckeditor is never displayed in js files ?

Comment: If you are posting on a mobile phone, please either locate your Shift key, or swap to a PC or laptop. Volunteer editors are willing to help make posts a bit more readable, but we are not your AutoCorrect. Please refrain from txtspk for the same reason, thanks!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Also, don't write "plzz help is urgent". It's considered very rude. You're asking for help from unpaid people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by adding

```
parent.append("<br /><form action='index.php' method='post' id='tog'><input 
type='text' name='uname2' id='uname2' placeholder='Name' required /><textarea 
name='editor' placeholder='Query' id='new-reply' required>
</textarea><input type='hidden' name='code' value='"+comCode+"' /><input 
type='submit' class='form-submit' id='form-reply' name='new_reply' 
value='Reply' /><script>CKEDITOR.replace('new-reply');</script></form>")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`CKEDITOR.replace`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) might be used only with DOM element, element's ID or element's name. From what I see in your code, you try to use it with class name. So in this short example you should use code like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'new-reply' )
```

Most probably there is an error in console which inform that, `ckeditor` cannot be found or sth similar.